# View all items in Task list restricted to logged user which belogs to "Project Managers" SharePoint Group

Tags: office-365

I have a Task list in Office 365 and I want to filter "All tasks" view with the following requirement:
- Logged user must view only assigned tasks.
- If logged user is in a special SharePoint group (for example "Project Managers") he must view all the tasks.

First point is easy to achieve, but I don't find how can I achieve second point.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can not do a Group Filter with View Settings, you have to set the Target Audience on another ListView webpart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the same view for both purposes then you can add another user field (ProjectManagersGroup)to the list and set that field to the project managers group each time a task is created (can be done easily using SP Designer). Then you can change the view query to show tasks based on either user == assigned to OR users is a member of the ProjectManagers group.

```
<Membership  Type="CurrentUserGroups"><FieldRef Name="ProjectManagersGroup"/></Membership>
```

Comment: +1. Good solution.